# Need to remove unwanted characters from string

Tags: php, utf8-decode

i have string which contains characters like

```
TrÃ  Hoa Viá»‡t
```

the want to Convert like this

```
Trà Hoa Việt
```

already tried by php

`iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", "TrÃ  Hoa Viá»‡t")`

but unable to remove the and get original format that i wanted. please help in this

Thank you.

Comment: You have to give us more information about the origin of the byte sequence and the medium that displays the string.

Comment: Thank you Volker for quick comment ,  Actually this string is store in database just this is case , i tried some online site to convert it to utf8 they convert this one perfectly as i needed , but not known how to do in php.

Comment: really simple : http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: Charset from DB juggling issue probably, "canonical" answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: And even if you don't want to/can't use utf-8 this thread treats all necessary steps and stages involved.